# Xml parsing in Android, Null exception

Tags: android, xpath, xml-parsing

i have an xml that looks this way

```
<Quiz>
<Inhalt Frage="test" number="1" />
<Inhalt Frage ="test2" number=2"/> 
</Quiz>
```

Now, in android i want to parse this xml in that way, that the result show me the content
of "Frage" for the number 2. I have tried to parse it this way, but i always get a nullexception error:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr= xpath.compile("//Frage[@number=2]/text()");

Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
einga= nodes.item(0).getNodeName();
```

Would be great, if someone could help me with this. 
Thank you :-)

Comment: You are trying to select the text from the node Frage which have an attribute number with the value 2.
Are you familiar with Xpath expressions ? Try this link : http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Try : "/Quiz/Inhalt[@number=2]@Frage"

You will get test2

Comment: Thank you, but When i try this, i get the error: Extra illegal tokens '@','Frage'

Comment: it worked this way:XPathExpression expr= xpath.compile("//Inhalt[@nummer='2']/@Frage");

Comment: Right... there was a `/` missing before the `@` in @Stephane's suggestion. In regard to learning XPath: please don't use w3schools, unless you want to have to unlearn their mistakes later. (See http://w3fools.com/) Instead try http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/General/examples.html

Comment: @StephaneMathis, could you make your comment into an answer? Then, this question will no longer be categorized as "unanswered", and Basem can "accept" your answer if he wants to. (And you will likely get more rep.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to select the text from the node Frage which have an attribute number with the value 2. Are you familiar with Xpath expressions? Try this link : http://w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp

Try : `"//Inhalt[@number='2']/@Frage"`. You will get test2